# Scrolling in DialogViewController broke cell tapped event

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to implement an infinite scroll in Xamarin.IOS using the MTD framework. To accomplish that, I handled the Scrolled event from the TableView property but as soon as I define an handler for that event, all the Tapped event of my elements (which are all StyledStringElement) stop working, the handler isn't called anymore. Even if I unsubscribe to the event later in my code, as soon as I "touch" the Scrolled event, cell Tapped break.

Here's what I do to handle the scroll event:

```
_root_ViewController = new DialogViewController(_rootElement);
_root_ViewController.TableView.Scrolled += TableView_Scrolled;
```

Here's how I create my cells :

```
StyledStringElement newCell = new StyledStringElement(item.Name)
{Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator };
newCell.Tapped+=()=> _nav.PushViewController(getDetailView(item.Name, item.ID), true);
```

Any ideas ? If it's a bug or something that shouldn't be done, what would be the proper way to implement an infinite scrolling ? I've to detect that the user is approching the bottom of the table to "prefetch" the next page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the event-based system and the native delegate-based system of UIKit are mutually exclusive.   That means that if you use events, you can not use delegates, and if you use delegates, you can not use events.

The TableView that you are accessing happens to have a delegate handler set by MonoTouch.Dialog, so when you provide events, it resets the internal handling for it.

The only solution to this is to subclass the internal Tableview delegate and provide that as your delegate to intercept those messages.